# Phpmyadmin not connecting in xampp using PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I tried to access the phpmyadmin using public ip.But cant able to connect.It showing error like

> "Access denied for user 'root'@'u15306256.onlinehome-server.com' (using password: NO)".

Recently I changed the phpmyadmin version.I don know whether its create problem or not.

Anyone help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: what means by  **using public ip** ?

Comment: Are you able to access it locally?

Comment: open mysql console and try accessing mysql using same credentials. See it gives access locally or not.

Comment: it access locally.Using remote ip only i am facing problem

Comment: put online. Refer [link](http://www.expertcore.org/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=1547)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
Starting from

```
server configurations
```

To have phpmyadmin work properly from a remote host, you also need to ensure that in the phpmyadmin config file that you use your outside IP address (not 127.0.0.1 or 'localhost')

But remember! XAMPP is only meant for local developing! If u open it to the public u might get hacked.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
grant all on *.* to root@u15306256
```

Comment: where i need to give this one